# How to make superscripts bold within an expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, axis-labels

I'm trying to make an axis title which includes superscript and subscript but also need the whole title to be in bold. When I place bold after expression, only the normal text becomes bold, leaving the superscript and subscript in a plain typeface. 
How do I make the whole title bold?

```
plot+labs(y=expression(bold(paste("L",og[10]," cell concentration (cells ",ml^-1,")",sep=""))))
```

this is my code so far, 10 and -1 are sub and superscripted as needed, but not in bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using numbers (10 and -1) for subscript and superscript respectively, use text ("10" and "-1"):

```
labs(y=expression(bold(paste("L",og["10"]," cell concentration (cells ",ml^"-1",")",sep=""))))
```